# Passing to Linux's "here string" via Java

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to pass a string to a Linux command using [<<<](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80362/what-does-mean):

```
cat <<< 'Hello'
```

While this works perfectly in the terminal, Java does not execute this

```
String cmd = "cat <<< 'Hello'";
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd.split(" ")).start();
String stderr = IOUtils.toString(p.getErrorStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
String stdout = IOUtils.toString(p.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
System.out.println(stderr);
```

with an error from terminal:

```
cat: '<<<': No such file or directory
cat: "'hello'": No such file or directory
```

Why is that so? Commands without `<<<` get executed in the usual manner.

Comment: because input and output redirection is a *shell* feature.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thanks. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Open a shell by calling 'bash' (String cmd='bash') or whatever you like, then use the stdio (p.getOutputstream) to write the command to the shell, and p.getInputstream to read results

Comment: Whatever you’re trying to do, it probably can be done by just representing the here-string as a String in your program.

Comment: @VGR what do you mean by 'representing the here-string as a String'? It is already inside a String called cmd.

Comment: I mean `String input = "Hello";`.  You can then wrap the value of `p.getOutputStream()` in an [OutputStreamWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html), and write `input` to that OutputStreamWriter.

Comment: Note that `<<<` works by creating a temporary file, writing the string to it, and connecting that file to stdin. You can of course do all this yourself in Java and not be relying on shell features at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, `<<<` is a capability of shells, like bash.  You *could* invoke bash from your ProcessBuilder… but really, you don’t need a here-string.  You have Java.

Here’s how to pass known input to a command:

```
String input = "Hello";

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cat");
builder.inheritIO();
builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);
Process p = builder.start();

try (Writer processInput =
    new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset())) {

    processInput.write(input);
}
```

The [inheritIO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) method of ProcessBuilder will cause the subprocess’s standard output to appear in the Java program’s standard output, and similarly, the subprocess’s standard error will appear in the Java program’s standard error.

If you want to capture the standard output of the process, you can replace `inheritIO()` with an explicit call to [redirectError](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectError(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect)):

```
String input = "Hello";

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cat");
builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = builder.start();

try (Writer processInput =
    new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset())) {

    processInput.write(input);
}

try (BufferedReader processOutput = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset()))) {

    String line;
    while ((line = processOutput.readLine()) != null) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

`processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", cmd`);

In general output redirection is shell feature and ProcessBuilder is not able to understand the command in the way you gave it.